# Alternatives to XCopy for copying lots of files?

Tags: xcopy

The situation: I have a pieceofcrapuous laptop. One of the things that make it pieceofcrapuous is that the battery is dead, and the power cable pulls out of the back with little effort.

I recently received a non-pieceofcrapuous laptop, and I am in the process of copying everything from old to new. I'm trying to xcopy c:*.* from the old machine to an external hard drive, but because the cord pulls out so frequently, the xcopy is interrupted fairly often.

What I need is a switch in XCopy that will copy eveything except for files that already exist in the destination folder -- the exact opposite of the behavior of the /U switch.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

/D may be what you are looking for. I find it works quite fast for backing-up as existing files are not copied.

```
xcopy "O:\*.*" N:\Whatever /C /D /S /H 

/C Continues copying even if errors occur. 
/D:m-d-y Copies files changed on or after the specified date. 
    If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time 
    is newer than the destination time. 
/S Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones. 
/H Copies hidden and system files also.
```

More information: http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

Comment: Excellent. This is 3 years old and it was the perfect answer to my question.

Answer (score 15):

I find RoboCopy is a good alternative to xcopy. It supports high latency connections much better and supports resuming a copy.

#### References

[Wikipedia - robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)

#### Downloads

**Edit** Robocopy was introduced as a standard feature of Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.

- Robocopy is shipped as part of the Windows Server 2003 resource kit and can be download from the [Microsoft download site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).
- A very simple GUI has also been release for RoboCopy on technet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc160891.aspx

Comment: It's also included in Vista default installation now.

Answer (score 4):

[Beyond Compare 3](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) is the best utility I've seen for things like this. It makes everything really easy to assess, and really easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php).

Answer (score 2):

It was not clear if you only wanted a command line tool, but Microsoft's free [SyncToy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy) program is great for maintaining a replication between a pair of volumes. It supports pushing changes in either or both directions. That is, it support several different types of replication modes.

Answer (score 1):

XcopyGUI. A small, standalone GUI front-end for xcopy. Free. http://lorenstuff.weebly.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
robocopy c:\sourceDirectory\*.* d:\destinationDirectory\*.* /R:5 /W:3 /Z /XX /TEE
```

This will work for your alternative to xCopy... best method imho

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [rsync](http://optics.ph.unimelb.edu.au/help/rsync/rsync_pc1.html), several ports are available, but [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) seems to work nicely on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

How about [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)?